# How do I make face into moveable door?

Tags: modeling, animation, edit-mode, faces, sculpting

I'm wanting to make this face into a door where it can open and close, but I'm not sure how to go about it... I'm wondering if I should use bones or just regular object keyframes to animate it... What is the best way to go about this? The face is shown and highlighted in the screenshot below:

[image: Highlighted face that needs to be door]

Comment: You could create a new object and put its origin where its hinge is supposed to be and that's enough

Comment: @moonboots can now explain you how you can open and close the door by wind with a hinge....!!!! :D

Comment: @Chris You can only open it if it's a little bit unhinged, that's how Blender works!!

Comment: @Chris :D If he already found out how it's done best ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

In Edit mode you can separate a face with P -> then just change the origin point to a suitable point and then you can rotate the new object as you want.

Comment: Should I parent the door to the building? I'd like them to be the same object, just a moveable part...

Comment: yes you should! It is not necessary for the animation but if you move the building the door will move with it which makes sense.